# Create the database with __MigrationHistory in EF Core6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using .NET Core 6 and EF Core 6 with an existing database. We had to make a few changes to this database so we introduced EF Core 6 migrations. To make it work with the initial database we had to create an empty initial creation. So when we run the migration script the new columns are added.

The question is: How can I create an initial database for development purposes on the local machine?

If I use this approach

```
var databaseCreator = (RelationalDatabaseCreator)dbContext.Database.GetService<IDatabaseCreator>();

await databaseCreator.CreateTablesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

The tables are created, but without the migration history, so subsequent migrations will fail.

If I just run the migration with

```
await context.Database.MigrateAsync(cancellationToken);
```

The tables will not be created because my initial migration is empty.

What is the correct approach here to init an empty database with the migration history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I solved this myself was by generating a full initial migration based on the current model (not an empty migration), like the database would not exist yet. Then call `MigrateAsync` on a new local database. That will insert that migration into your local __MigrationHistory table. Then you insert that row from your local __MigrationHistory table into your production database's __MigrationHistory table.

Now your production database will skip the initial migration, but if you need it for another database, you can build it from scratch.

Comment: This would work, but it depends on the number of production databases. For an OnPremise solution it would not work.

Comment: @SebastianStehle I don't understand what you mean? What depends on the number of production databases? And what is the problem with an on premise solution?

Comment: I mean your solution works, but it sucks that there is no easy automation. But I guess your solution is the best

Comment: Yeah I agree this scenario is not straightforward to solve...